# How to change the 'Projects' permalink to the Category of the post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I would like to change the permalinks for projects to use the specific post's parent category name. Is this possible? I have come across a few tutorials via Google, though none seem specific to this cause.

I am currently using the Wordpress Projects section for Events and a Menu (restaurant). I would like the URLs associated with the posts in each of those categories to be /events/post-name and /menu/post-name

From:

www.website.com/projects/post-name

To:

www.website.com/events/post-name

www.website.com/menu/post-name

Comment: Make a "projects" parent category, and then create each individual project as child post of the parent. Then you should see website.com/projects/example1 for each url.

Comment: I am actually trying to move away from having /projects/ in the URL. I am currently using the Wordpress Projects section for Events and a Menu (restaurant). I would like the URLs associated with the posts in each of those categories to be /events/_PostName_ and /menu/_PostName_

Answer (score 0):

The *Yoast SEO* plugin can help you for doing this kind of URL manipulation.

Also, it seems you need to create [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) for your different kinds of contents. In your case, you can create an **Events** post type and a **Menu** post type.

There are several plugins available to help you with Custom Post Types, for exemple: [Custom Post Type UI](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/), [Toolset Types](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/types/)...

And this one: [post-type-switcher](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/) can be useful if you want to transfer your existing content in a newly created Post Type.

Hope it will help